# Why is MATLAB interp2 Much Faster Than SciPy on Non-Uniformly Spaced Samples?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, scipy, interpolation

I have an image projection issue, where in the final step, I need to use bilinear interpolation on a source image to destination points that are non-uniformly spaced. MATLAB handles this great, and computes an answer very quickly using `interp2`. MATLAB example:

```matlab
img = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
img = double(rgb2gray(img)) / 256;
[img_col, img_row] = meshgrid(1:size(img, 2), 1:size(img, 1));
interp_rows = 325+200*randn(1, 100000);
interp_cols = 300*200*randn(1, 100000);

tic
img_interp = interp2(img_col, img_row, omg, interp_rows, interp_cols)
toc
>Elapsed time is 0.011680 seconds.
```

So far as I can tell, there is no way to interpolate to non-uniformly sampled points nearly as fast in Python. All the typical SciPy methods seem to want the target to *also* be a 2D grid of equally spaced points, rather than a random scatter of points. (E.g. `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`). Doing this same operation in SciPy requires a for-loop:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np


% Does NOT interpolate to points outside the convex hull (which is good)
interpolator = interp2d(img_col, img_row, img)
interp_rows = 325+200*np.random.randn(1, 100000);
interp_cols = 300*200*np.random.randn(1, 100000);

result = np.empty((100000,), dtype=np.float)
for i in range(100000):
    result[i] = interpolator(interp_cols[i], interp_rows[i])
```

As one might expect with the loop this takes, a **very long time**. I am sure there must be a better way. The closest thing I have found is `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`. With this, I can *almost* do what I want with near the same speed as MATLAB:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

% DOES interpolate to points outside the convex hull (which is bad)
interpolator = RectBivariateSpline(img_col, img_row, img)
img_interp = interpolator(interp_cols, interp_rows, grid=False)
```

The problem with this method, is that it does not set values outside the source convex hull to NaN. It still interpolates to those values. This then requires finding the convex hull and eliminating values outside of the hull manually, which is slow.

Comment: There are many questions here about Python being slower than MATLAB. Python is free, MATLAB is not. You can choose, cheap or fast.

Comment: This is not true at all. Usually people just don't know how to write fast code in Python :)

Comment: "The problem with this method, is that it does not set values outside the source convex hull to NaN. It still interpolates to those values." The convex hull of the source (the image) is a rectangle (or am I missing something)?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, the main issue, is that I feel like I must be missing something. It seems like Python must have a similarly fast method.

Comment: @Trilarion, in this made up example the convex hull of the source image is a rectangle. That isn't necessarily always the case. Furthermore, the target points may be outside of that shape.

Comment: Not necessarily must there be a similarly fast method. There is no guarantee that Python with SciPy is as good as Matlab. But actually there is a similarly fast method as you describe, only it's not doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the for-loop you are using:

```
for i in range(100000):
    result[i] = interpolator(interp_cols[i], interp_rows[i])
```

With you MATLAB code you are using a vectorized approach:

```
img_interp = interp2(img_col, img_row, omg, interp_rows, interp_cols)
```

The same is possible with scipy:

```
result = interpolator(interp_cols, interp_rows)
```

This should give you a pretty good speed-up.

Avoid for-loops in Python. Usually there is a vectorized approach in Numpy / Scipy.

MATLAB might still be slightly faster, but when you are seeing computation times that are maybe 2 to 100 times slower, you are doing something wrong in Python.

For comparison, you can try to add the for-loop to MATLAB and see how it performs.

See [here](http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/optimizing/index.html) or [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/02/24/optimizing-python-with-numpy-and-numba/) for ideas and concepts,

Comment: As an addition, the "standard" installation of numpy will likely be single threaded, while MATLAB has very efficient multi-core implementation of these operations. On my 64 core machine, I can see MATLAB use them all for every simple vector operation, while numpy does not. That said, yes, vectorization is likely the main factor here.

Comment: Some operations in numpy are parallel in the background. See e.g. https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/ParallelProgramming and https://www.quora.com/How-does-NumPy-make-parallel-computations-Where-can-I-get-the-algorithms-of-NumPy-functions-and-their-implementations

Comment: Unfortunately, the trouble with the SciPy interpolator is that it does not accept a scatter of input points. It only accepts ranges for the input points. Basically, the target points have to be a grid, they can't be a random scatter the way they can be in MATLAB.

Comment: MATLAB interp2d also only takes gridded data: "interp2 Interpolation for 2-D gridded data in meshgrid format"

Comment: But there are other interpolation functions in scipy that allow for scattered data:

Comment: Rbf https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf

Comment: LinearNDInterpolator https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator

Comment: Or Matplotlib's LinearTriInterpolator https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/tri_api.html#matplotlib.tri.LinearTriInterpolator [example here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/triinterp_demo.html)

Comment: This one is a wrapper for several interpolators https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html and allows to use unstructured n-dimensional data.